# If $f(x) = x^2 - 2x + 5$ what is $f^{-1}(x)$?

Tags: functions

> If $f(x) = x^2 - 2x + 5$ what is $f^{-1}(x)$?
> **with the condition : $x > 1$**

I solved this problem in this way:

> $f(x) = x^2 - 2x + 5 -1 +1 \longrightarrow (x-2)^2 + 1 = f(x) $

> $f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt{x-1} + 2$

But I saw someone else solved it in this way:

> $f(x) = x^2 - 2x + 1 + 4  \longrightarrow  (x+1)^2 + 4 = f(x)  $

> $f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt{x-4} + 1$

Which one is correct? If the second one is correct why mine is wrong?

Comment: Both are not correct

Comment: $$
(x - 2)^2  + 1 = x^2  - 4x + 5 \ne f(x) ,\qquad 
(x + 1)^2  + 4 = x^2  + 2x + 5 \ne f(x)
$$

Comment: $f(x)$ is not one-one .

Comment: @WeAreBeingWatched I just showed that the expressions you claimed for $f(x)$ after completing squares are not true. In fact, $x^2  - 2x + 5 = (x - 1)^2  + 4$.

Comment: @Gary I edited the problem what about now? which would be correct?

Comment: As Lion Heart said, non are correct. Look at my last comment for the correct expression.

Comment: Now it is one-one by the condition   $ x>1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x)=y= x^2-2x+5=x^2-2x+4+1=(x-1)^2+4$$

$$(x-1)^2=y-4$$

$$x-1=\pm\sqrt{y-4} $$

$$x=\pm\sqrt{y-4}+1$$

Interchange $x$ and $y$

$$f^{-1}(x)=y=\pm\sqrt{x-4}+1$$

for $x>1$ inverse of f, $f^{-1}(x)=y=\sqrt{x-4}+1$

Answer (score 3):

After the edit, in the given interval $f(x)$ is bijective and hence invertible. But your method is incorrect because:
$$(x-2)^2+1=x^2-4x+5\neq f(x)$$
Your friend is right, but I believe in the second-last step you meant $f(x)=(x-1)^2+4$